# Prove that $pq$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$ in two different ways

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

I want to prove that if $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$ are primes and $p\neq q$, then $pq$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$ (with $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$) in two different ways, that is, $pq=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ with $\{a,b\}\neq\{c,d\}$.

I know that if $p\in \mathbb{N}$ is prime, then $p$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$ in an unique way, because if I factorise in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain.

I have tried using this to solve the original problem. I am guessing I should do something like
$$pq=(a+bi)(a-bi)(c+di)(c-di)$$
and then grouping the factors in two different ways. However I am stuck here. Can someone help me?

Comment: "I know that if $p\in \mathbb{N}$ is prime, then $p$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$ in an unique way". Here you want to say that $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, right?

Comment: Is the statement true if you take $p = 3$ and $q = 5$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general statement is not correct. For instance, take $p=2,\thinspace q=3$ then you get

$$x^2+y^2=6$$

which implies $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ doesn't exist.

---

The correct statement can be considered as follows:

Let $p,q$ be distinct primes and $x,y,u,v\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ such that,

$$p=x^2+y^2,q=u^2+v^2;p,q\not\in\left\{2\right\}$$

then we have,

$$(x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2)=(ux+vy)^2+(uy-vx)^2$$

and

$$(x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2)=(ux-vy)^2+(uy+vx)^2$$

Note that, iff $p=2$ or $q=2$ then we have unique sum of squares:

$$(1^2+1^2)(u^2+v^2)=(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2.$$

I leave it to you to analyze why the numbers containing the sum of squares differ in the case of $p,q\not\in\left\{2\right\}$.

Comment: Oh actually, it is clean enough. Suppose that the two equations are equal. Case 1. $uy + vx = uy - vx$ (WLOG, can assume $uy \ge vx$). This clearly gives $vx = 0$, a contradiction. Case 2. $uy + vx = ux + vy$. Rearrange to get $u(y - x) = v(y - x)$. In turn, $(u - v)(y - x) = 0$. But $u = v$ or $x = y$ forces one of those primes to be even, i.e., $2$.

Comment: @Aryaman +1 to your comment. This completes my answer.

Comment: And i upvoted you

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your credit $\ddot\smile$

Comment: How did you find these factorizations? Did you already know them or did you use some method to find them?

Comment: @kubo I knew beforehand.  Because, this is the famous sum of squares formula.